# StackExchange Single Sign on

Tags: discussion, authentication

What is the technique or procedure used in implementing Single Sign On in StackExchange websites?
Whether it is possible to implement custom authentication providers so that the site credentials can be used to login to other sites which is not hosted by same organization?

Comment: [Is this what you're looking for?](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/authentication)

Comment: Or maybe [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/global-network-auto-login/)?

Comment: thanks, that is what I am looking for